# cut, copy and paste with speech recognition in C#

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence

I'm developing a windows application that using speech recognition. Now I want to add copy, paste and cut to my application. I mean when I select a word or sentence and say copy, the application copy that and when I say paste, paste it. How to do that? Another question, how can I change between windows with speech? (alt+tab with voice)

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand? Are you asking for the `Clipboard` class?

Comment: i didn't tried anything (find some codes for copy and paste but i don't know how to use it in speech recognition). i can't understand how speech recognition work and how to open files - copy files .... with speech, how can i find the codes for those things ... . yes, please and please explain it.